# limit of Lebesgue integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a real valued, Lebesgue integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \int_{\mathbb R} |f(x+t)-f(x)|\, dx=0.$$

I thought that maybe I should use the following fact, But I couldn't find a way to solve the question based on the fact. how can I use it to solve the question?

fact: I know that if $f$ is a Borel measurable function, we have for $a \in  {\mathbb R}$

$\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} f(x) dx= \int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} f(x-a) dx$

Maybe I should use another theorem. Should I?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** This statement is much easier to prove when you assume $f$ is of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i \chi_{(a_i,b_i]}$, i.e, $f$ is a simple function whose base sets are all intervals. Using the fact that such functions are dense in $L_1$, approximate $f$ with an $\phi$ of this form, then write
$$
|f(x)-f(x+t)|\le |f(x)-\phi(x)|+|\phi(x)-\phi(x+t)|+|\phi(x+t)-f(x+t)|
$$
The fact that this type of simple function is dense in $L_1$ is responsible for making a lot of surprising theorems like this very doable (it is also helpful in proving $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx=0$).

Comment: I really appriciate your help, but the question doesn't mention that f is a simple function.

Comment: I know, you don't need that $f$ is a simple function. But for any $f\in L_1$, and any $\epsilon>0$, there will exist a simple function $\phi$ in the form I described for which $|f-\phi|_1<\epsilon$. The last statement is the fact that is helpful.